# TweenMax.js on local server (MAMP) does not properly initialise - throws error

Tags: javascript, macos, mamp, gsap

I am running a local server (MAMP) on MacOS. When I open the .php (html) file of a webpage with TweenMax on it http://localhost:8888/Index.php/ The page loads fine, but the tweens do not work at all. The browser console gives error: "Uncaught Cannot tween a null target."

When I run the exact same page in browser but the page is hosted on a remote server: https://depicture.io/, tweenmax works. Why is there such difference? Shouldn't the behaviour of how scripts are executed be the same between local server and remote server?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I could not find anyone having a similar issue.

I also get this error:

```
DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
    at Function.CSSRulePlugin.getRule (http://localhost:8888/Depicture/js/CSSRulePlugin.js:53:19)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/Depicture/:2077:29)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:7857)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:8658)
    at Function.ready (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:3266)
    at HTMLDocument.H (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:695)
```

which points to this line:

```
var rule = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(".grid__item span::after");
```

The CSSRulePlugin is loaded in as it should and works fine on remote server.

Comment: what is the 'tween target' on local and remote server. it's difficult to answer without knowing the setup of the servers, are they running the exact same code, you using the same browser to view it on? if your using the JS version of TweenMax (which it looks like you are) then the server shouldn't make a difference. JS runs in the browser. is your JS loading any assets or whatever that have a hardcoded local path?

Comment: I am not sure about tween target, but it should be the same between servers as the code is exactly the same. I am using the same browser and pulling the JS version of TweenMax from CDN on both servers (same link) and it loads fine (no issues with CORS or stuff like that). there is no absolute linking, it is all relative so should not make any difference. This is the link: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kvyb/32f40d81ef16d0ff2da87bdc82601dc9/raw/6ba221f062cf4ae2f8c870bd0bd08e1feea43018/index.php  (style ends on 1724) sorry for messy code.

Comment: Are both servers running the exact same versions of PHP, set up in the same way?

Comment: Yes, I just checked. However even if they did not why would this be a problem if there is no PHP script involved (except the form which works fine).

Comment: PHP shouldn't be an issue here, is just html and js. I imagine it is more than likely a 404 error. check the network tab in your browser to make sure everything is loading as expected in both local and remote. there must be a difference somewhere between the two environments. maybe a file not added to git / uploaded. could be permissions or missing asset.

Comment: No errors except TweenMax. I have updated the question.

Comment: If it's the target that is null, then what you are trying to select is not found. You are using an old version of jQuery, but seems unlikely to be the problem. What are you trying to animate? Could it be an image/object that hasn't been loaded on local?

Comment: Hello Paul. It is a <span> object within a div. I animate its pseudoelement :before :after with CSSRulePlugin. However, even simple animation of <div> with logo does not work.

Comment: i think that on your localhost there is 0 delay on your script loading and executing.   so when you run it, because it instantly runs it cannot find the target, but using a webserver you possibly have a natural delay, enough that it finds the target.   If you are 100% sure the target does indeed exist, this can be found by debugging or just pushing the target value out in your console.log     you can try to wrap your tweenmax / javascript in a document on ready  or something equivelant

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the sequence of steps mentioned here: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/greensock

Install via npm, or use directly the cdn url as below

VIA NPM-

```
npm install gsap
```

VIA CDN-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Then in your code import it as below-

```
//typical import 
import {TweenMax, Power2, TimelineLite} from "gsap";

//or get to the parts that aren't included inside TweenMax (works as of 1.19.1): 
import Draggable from "gsap/Draggable";
import ScrollToPlugin from "gsap/ScrollToPlugin";
```

I think that should work.

Comment: This is unlikely to solve it as it looks as though GSAP is loading, but what he is targeting is not being found